# Staging directories in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

We have few staging directories in yocto build like
STAGING_INCDIR, STAGING_INCDIR_NATIVE STAGING_DIR_HOST STAGING_DIR

For these respective recipe-sysroot* folders are created under work directory.

I need help to understand the usage of different sysroot directories in the work directories and how file imported into this directories.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score -1):

It's all listed in the manual: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-STAGING_BASE_LIBDIR_NATIVE

Comment: Looks like the link is dead and the edit queue is full. Please correct above to: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-STAGING_BASE_LIBDIR_NATIVE